# Anaconda environment not using packages saved in the environment

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda, conda, anaconda3

I created an environment using the command `conda create -n myenv python=3.9`. I entered the environment using `conda activate myenv`, and did not install any packages. When I try to run a file using `python3 my_file` which imports NumPy without a problem. This is because it accesses packages stored at a different location: `c:\users\zador\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python39\site-packages`. I figured this out by uninstalling at that location, and indeed the code did not run.

Additionally, I tried to get install NumPy in my new environment so I ran both `conda install numpy` and `pip3 install numpy`, and after both installations I got the error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'`.

I don't get what's going on. I am in my environment but packages are being accessed at a different location.

Some additional information that may or may not be helpful:

After the command `where python`, I get the output:

```
C:\Users\zador\anaconda3\envs\myenv\python.exe
C:\Users\zador\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\python.exe`
```

but after the command `where python3`, I get the output:

```
C:\Users\zador\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\python3.exe
```

Any help would be very much appreciated! When in a conda environment I want to access packages installed in that environment.

Comment: You already figured it out. There is no `python3` in your environment. After activating your environment, simply run `python <your File>` which will run the python 3.9 that you have installed in that environment

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response! Interesting, I had thought that python3 command always ran python 3.x, while python command runs python 2.x. Seems like this is not the case?

Comment: python3 or even python3.9 executables are sometimes added by installers to make them seperable from other python installations in case were you are not using virtual environments. In any case, each python installation usually has a python executable. Since `conda` has only one python version per environment, there is no need to add these extra binaries, since `python` and `pip` point to the versions installed in that environment

Comment: Okay perfect. Thanks for your help!